# how this.toggleProperty("editing") works in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

code

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  editing: false,
  actions: {
      editTodo() {
          this.toggleProperty("editing");
      },
      submitTodo() {
          const todo = this.get("todo");
          if (todo.get("title") == "") {
              todo.destroyRecord().then(() => {
                  this.toggleProperty("editing");
              });
          } else {
              this.toggleProperty("editing");
          }
      },
      deleteTodo() {
          this.get("todo").destroyRecord();
      }
  }
});
```

how this 'editing' property get into action, can anyone please explain? I'm new to ember

Answer (score 3):

First of all this looks like older ember code. In modern ember I would just do:

```js
@tracked editing = false;

@action
editTodo() {
  this.editing = !this.editing;
}
...
```

this also explains how the old `toggleProperty` works. [Its basically this:](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v3.26.1/packages/%40ember/-internals/runtime/lib/mixins/observable.js#L483)

```
toggleProperty(name) {
  this.set(name, !this.get(name));
}
```

which (if you understand the old embers `get` and `set`) is *basically* this:

```
toggleProperty(name) {
  this[name] = !this[name];
}
```

but also notifies ember about the changed property so ember will update the DOM. Modern ember does not need it because it uses `@tracked` to mark the state and the rest will *just work*.